# How do I group my data-set by month and apply SUM aggregation using Pandas/Python

Tags: sorting, date, pandas

I have the following Data-set df:

```
| date      | Revenue |
|-----------|---------|
| 6/1/2017  | 100     |
| 5/21/2017 | 200     |
| 5/20/2017 | 300     |
| 6/22/2017 | 400     |
| 6/20/2017 | 500     |
```

I need to group the above data by month and write Python code to get the following output:

```
| date | SUM(Revenue) |
|------|--------------|
| May  | 500          |
| June | 1000         |
```

I tried with the following code but got an error:

```
import pandas as pd
files='C:\\Users\\Month.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(files, parse_dates=['date'])
df = df.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True)
pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format = '%Y%m%d')
df2=df.sort_values('date',ascending=True)
df2.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).sum()
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of your dataset

Comment: 5/1/2017
5/2/2017
5/4/2017
5/5/2017
5/8/2017
5/9/2017
5/11/2017
5/15/2017
5/18/2017
5/25/2017
5/26/2017
5/21/2017
5/22/2017
5/23/2017
5/24/2017
5/28/2017
5/29/2017
5/30/2017
5/31/2017
5/10/2017
5/14/2017
5/1/2017
5/2/2017
5/3/2017
5/8/2017
5/9/2017
5/10/2017
5/15/2017

Comment: basically after 5/18, 5/19 it jumps to 5/2, 5/20 (which is wrong)

Comment: That doesn't include all the data according to your code. I need to see your entire dataframe

Answer (score 0):

specify the which ones is the month(m) or day(d) and then proceed with sort

```
pd.to_datetime(gdf['sale_date'],format='%m%d%Y')
gdf.sort('sale_date',ascending=False)
```